# Vimeo embed on webpage causes an error

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, expressionengine, vimeo-player

I'm trying to troubleshoot a strange bug on one of our pages (https://www.bbg.org/visit/sakura_matsuri_photos). 
The bottom of left of the page has the text 'cp_vimeo_code.js Open' and I can't figure out what is generating this. 
[here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRLvl.png)

I've noticed that there are other websites that show this error too, for example: https://www.indicia.nl/project/anderson-macgyver/.

I have the following three embeds inside the body tag of a webpage in Expression Engine. Taking them out eliminates the error.

```html
<div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/210978232?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/210978156?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/160249045?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Has anyone seen something like this before? I can't find it on Vimeo's site anywhere.
[Here is a picture of the error on our page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbsH4.png)

Comment: Not able to see the 'cp_vimeo_code.js Open' on the referenced page at the moment.  Is this resolved or removed?  If unresolved can you update to point to a page where the bug is present?

Comment: look at : https://www.bbg.org/visit/sakura_matsuri_photos, the error is at the very bottom of the page on the left side in white.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not resolved. I've contacted Vimeo but so far they have not been helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured where this was coming from, it was some extra code in a Google Tag Manger custom tag!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a call from an addon, that's trying to load a .js file for use in the control panel. However, since you're not in the CP it'll show the call as text.
Maybe see if the addon needs updating, or, since there are a lot of video player addons that have been abbandoned, need replacing

More indepth answers can be found on EE's own Stack: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/